# Canonical projection of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ onto $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Suppose we have a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with sufficiently smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. The Sobolev spaces $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ are defined as usual. I am wondering if there is a kind of "canonical projection" of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ onto $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, which of course should be linear and continuous.

My question comes from a variational problema that I can roughly describe as follows: I have a "bunch" of differential equations, each of which is defined on a domain $\Omega_R$ with (homogeneous) Dirichlet boundary condition. These equations "tend" to a limit equation that is defined on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^N$. Since they are variational in nature, I would like to introduce a unique functional space to include all of them, and therefore my idea is to pick any element of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, project it onto $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega_R)$ (which is the *natural* space) and then insert this into a functional. I dont want to introduce a different functional attached to each domain $\Omega_R$, since I would lose my limiting problem.

Comment: I think it is hopeless to find a canonical projection because the restriction of a function in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N)$ to $\Omega$ does not have zero trace on $\partial \Omega$ in general. Maybe you have to explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

A possible projection $u \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ of $v \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
 u = \operatorname{argmin}_{\tilde u \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)} \| \tilde u - v \|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}.
\end{equation*}
This $\operatorname{argmin}$ should exist in the reflexive case $1 < p < \infty$.
Moreover, this projection is linear in case $p = 2$.

An other possibility is by using an extension operator.
Let $\tau : W^{1,p}(\Omega) \to L^p(\partial\Omega)$ be the trace operator.
Then, there is a bounded right-inverse $E : \tau(W^{1,p}(\Omega)) \to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.
For $v \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, you have
\begin{equation*}
 v_{|\Omega} - E \, \tau(v_{|\Omega}) \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)
\end{equation*}
and this depends linearly on $v$. However, the extension operator is, of course,
not unique and there might be no ``canonical'' one.
For this second route, you also might need some conditions on $p$ for the existence of the extension operator.

Comment: Did you mean $\tau : W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to L^p(\partial \Omega)$?

Comment: @Tomás: Yes, of course. Thank you.